# Large deviations rate for binomial distributions

Tags: probability, large-deviation-theory

The problem is from Varadhan's Probability Theory, p.39, EXERCISE 3.7.

Can you calculate the geometric ratio $$\rho(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(\sum_{r\geq nx} \binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{2^n}\right)^{1/n}$$ explicitly as a function of $x$ for $x>1/2$?

Comment: Yes I can. And now, what did you try yourself?

Comment: I tried to write inside as a Riemann integral. In the prevous part of the question, it worked.

Comment: Hmmm... "it worked", really? Which techniques do you know that were actually used to solve other similar problems? For example in the book you are studying. (Integrals are certainly not among the most used...)

Comment: The problem is in the third chapter of the book (independent sums). It is an exercise in the section of weak law of large numbers.  I met the use of the characteristic functions and Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: "I met the use of the characteristic functions and Chebyshev's inequality." Perfect. How to apply these or one of these here?

Comment: Hmm, I guess we can apply the characteristic function and then look at the limit? No it doesn't work, does it? Also in the previous part of the exercise we used  Stirling's formula. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: No guess please. Once again, when you saw in the book that they wanted to estimate some probabilities of events, how did they do it?

Comment: In the previous part, the question is to estimate $\sum_{r\geq nx} \binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{2^n}$ using Stirling's formula. It is a geometric decay in $n$. Then, we are asked to calculate the above limit explicitly. We did not see  the central limit theorem yet.

Comment: If you know it is a geometric decay, you have your answer no?

Comment: No. Because, we know  $\sum_{r\geq nx} \binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{2^n}$ goes to zero geometrically in $n$ but we don't know explicitly the limit $(\sum_{r\geq nx} \binom{n}{r}\frac{1}{2^n})^{1/n}$.

Comment: Actually, partly yes, because what you did using Stirling gives you an explicit lower bound of $\rho(x)$. Did you write it down?

Comment: An explicit upper bound you mean, don't you?  It was something like $c2^{-n}$. But it seemed then to me that this was not the best upper bound.

Comment: You should try to write it down (and it was certainly not $c/2^n$).

Comment: Ok I will try it. In fact I see in Wikipedia that it is $exp(-NI(x))$. After writing it explicitly,  will we conclude that it is the best upper bound?

Comment: Ok, I think I solved it. As Did said you find a lower bound $exp(-N(I(x)))1/N^{1/2}$ and an upper bound. Then sandwich theorem gives the result.

Comment: @btm: Perhaps you could write up that solution as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think the function turns out as:

For $x>\frac{1}{2}$, we calculate
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{nx<r} {n\choose r}\frac{1}{2^n} &= \sum\limits_{nx<r} \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}\frac{1}{2^n} 
\\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{nx<r<n} \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi r}}\left(\frac{e}{r}\right)^r \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(n-r)}}\left(\frac{e}{n-r}\right)^{n-r}\frac{1}{2^n}f(n)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Stirling's formula has been used here and accordingly $f(n)$ converges to $1$ as $n\to \infty$.
Dropping the term $f(n)$, we proceed further
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\sum\limits_{nx<r} {n\choose r}\frac{1}{2^n} &\approx \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{nx < r < n} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi r(n-r)}}\exp{\left(n\log\frac{n}{e} - r\log\frac{r}{e} - (n-r)\log\frac{n-r}{e} +n\log\frac{1}{2}\right)} 
\\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{nx<r<n} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi r(n-r)}} \exp\left(n\log n -r\log r - (n-r)\log(n-r) + n\log\frac{1}{2}\right)
\\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{nx<r<n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n\frac{r}{n}(1-\frac{r}{n})}} \exp n\left(\log n -\frac{r}{n}\log r - \left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\log(n-r) + \log\frac{1}{2}\right)
\\
&= \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{nx<r<n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n\frac{r}{n}(1-\frac{r}{n})}} \exp n\left(-\frac{r}{n}\log \frac{r}{n} - \left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right)\log\left(1-\frac{r}{n}\right) + \log\frac{1}{2}\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Writing $\frac{r}{n}$ as $\alpha$ and $E(\alpha):=\alpha\log \alpha + (1-\alpha)\log(1-\alpha)$ for $\alpha \in \left[\frac{1}{2},1\right)$ this last term becomes
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&= \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{nx<r<n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n\alpha(1-\alpha)}}
\exp\left\lbrace-n\left(E(\alpha) - E(1/2) \right) \right\rbrace 
\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{nx<r<n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi n\alpha(1-\alpha)}}
\exp\left\lbrace -n \left(E(x) - E(1/2)\right)\right\rbrace
\end{split}
\end{equation}
This last inequality holds since $E(\alpha)$ is increasing. Further, since the function $\frac{1}{\alpha(1-\alpha)}$ is increasing for $\alpha \in [1/2,1)$ the previous quantity can be see to be
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
&\leq \frac{1}{2^n} + \sum\limits_{nx<r<n} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2\pi (n-1)}}
\exp\left\lbrace -n \left(E(x) - E(1/2)\right)\right\rbrace
\\
&\leq \frac{1}{2^n} + \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{n^{3/2}}{(n-1)^{1/2}}
\exp\left\lbrace -n \left(E(x) - E(1/2)\right)\right\rbrace
\\
&\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}n\exp\left\lbrace-n(E(x)- E(1/2)) \right\rbrace
\end{split}
\end{equation}
for all large enough $n$.
$E(x) - E(1/2)$ is positive so this quantity decays geometrically? Taking the $n$th root of this gives that
$$\rho(x) \leq \exp(E(1/2)-E(x)).
$$
Not sure how to prove what it is on the nose. Comments, corrections or suggestions are welcome.